# Getting Registration id value as null from the following code to implement C2DM using Android. ,Can anyone pls tell me what mistake am doing here ?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

```
           public void StartRegistrationNotification()
        {
            Intent registrationIntent = newIntent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
            registrationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
             registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
            registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "kanika.saya@gmail.com");
                   this.startService(registrationIntent);  
              Log.i("Recieve","1");
        }


            public class ReceiverC2DM extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver 

           {

     private static String KEY = "c2dmPref";
     private static String REGISTRATION_KEY = "registraionKey";
     private Context context;

    // wakelock
    private static final String WAKELOCK_KEY = "C2DM_FAX";
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.context = context;
          Toast.makeText(context,"At broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        runIntentInService(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context,"runIntentInService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            handleRegistration(context, intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"))     {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
        }
     }

    private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_key");
        Log.e("registration :","registration :"+registration);
        Toast.makeText(context,"registration :"+registration,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {
            // Registration failed, should try again later.
            Log.d("c2dm", "registration failed");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
            if(error == "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Service not available",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("c2dm", "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE");
            }
            else if(error == "ACCOUNT_MISSING"){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Account Missing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("c2dm", "ACCOUNT_MISSING");
            }else if(error == "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("c2dm", "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED");
            }else if(error == "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS"){
                Toast.makeText(context,"too many registration", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("c2dm", "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS");
            }else if(error == "INVALID_SENDER"){
                Toast.makeText(context,"invalid sender", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Log.d("c2dm", "INVALID_SENDER");
            }else if(error == "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR"){

                Log.d("c2dm", "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR");
            }
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null) {
            // unregistration done, new messages from the authorized sender will be rejected
            Log.d("c2dm", "unregistered");

        } else if (registration != null) {
            Log.d("c2dm", registration);
            Toast.makeText(context,"registration!=null="+registration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Editor editor =
                context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(REGISTRATION_KEY, registration);
            Toast.makeText(context,"registration :"+registration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              editor.commit();

           // Send the registration ID to the 3rd party site that is sending the messages.
           // This should be done in a separate thread.
            // When done, remember that all registration is done.
        }
    }
    private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

     String message = intent.getExtras().getString("payload");
     String key = intent.getExtras().getString("collapse_key");
     /*Log.e("","accountName : " +accountName);
     Log.e("","message : " +message);    
          Intent startActivity = new Intent(); 
            startActivity.setClass(context, NotificationAlert.class); 
            startActivity.setAction(NotificationAlert.class.getName()); 
            startActivity.setFlags( 
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);      
            startActivity.putExtra("Title", "Hello");
            startActivity.putExtra("Message", message);
            context.startActivity(startActivity);   
*/
          //Do whatever you want with the message         
              }

    static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (mWakeLock == null) {
                // This is called from BroadcastReceiver, there is no init.
                PowerManager pm = 
                        (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
                                WAKELOCK_KEY);
        }
        mWakeLock.acquire();

    }



}

    Manifest file is:

      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.synapse.reference"
      android:installLocation="auto"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="2.2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <permission android:name="com.synapse.reference.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.synapse.reference.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
      <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
      <!-- Send the registration id to the server -->

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />



      <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">                                                   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>



        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainMenuScreen">
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".ServerSimulator"/>    
          <activity android:name=".Information"/>
          <activity android:name=".About"/>

          <receiver android:name=".ReceiverC2DM"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <!-- Receive the actual message -->
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.synapse.reference" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.synapse.reference" />
        </intent-filter>
       </receiver>

       </application>
          </manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_key");
```

should actually be

```
String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: welcome..if the answer was useful consider it marking answered so that other developer will easily find it. its a tick mark on the left of the answer.